# Search option for checkbuttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

If we have some 2000-3000 checkbuttons, in order to select the particular checkbutton it is difficult. So is there any way for search option to check the checkbuttons string(same as text search inside textbox). Please share the code if you have any.

Thanks..

Searching for option to search the checkbuttons given the string associated with checkbutto

Comment: Why don't you just create a dictionary of checkbuttons, uniquely identifying each checkbutton by its key, which can also be passed as the bame argument to the Checkbutton function.
If you later can't find a specific Chekbutton, you can iterate over the dictionary values (checkbuttons) and match the one you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Mamg, Thank you for the suggestion. Is it possible share with an example code if you have. It will be helpful.